# Как правильно конвертировать enum в int?

Tags: c#, enum

Привет всем.

Наткнулся на то, что для конвертации enum в int необходимо производить явное преобразование.
Это работает, но как-то неудобно.

Можно ли как-то автоматизировать задачу или сделать более визуально "красивой"? Не хочется каждый раз для преобразования в int писать (int)enumVar

Comment: Если бы явная конвертация была не нужна, у вас бы скомпилировался код `Cars.BMW * Cars.Audi - 4 * Dogs.Terrier`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать метод расширения:

```
static class Extensions
{
    public static int ToInt(this MyEnum value)
    {
        return (int)value;
    }
}
```

После чего использовать:

```
enumVar.ToInt()
```

Но лично я не считаю, что это "красивее" и по-прежнему использовал бы приведение типа.